# Get data from AngularFirestoreCollection object

Tags: angularjs, ionic3, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an application on Ionic 3 with Cloud Firestore. I am stuck at how to retrieve the value in the snapshot retrieved from angularfirestorecollection. I am using the following function to access and process the data. But I am unable to understand how to get individual element values in the qd object

```
getQuoteTotal(status:string){
            this.qd=this.quoteprovider
                    .getQuoteList(status)
                    .snapshotChanges()
                     .map(actions => {
             return actions.map(a => {
   const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Quotation;
  const id = a.payload.doc.id;
   return { id, ...data }; // <-- how to access this data in rest of the function?
       })
     })
       return Array.from(this.qd)
               .map(res=>res.Price)
               .reduce((tot,price)=>tot+price,0)
}
```

Currently this throws the following

Typescript Error
Property 'Price' does not exist on type '{}'.

My aim is to calculate the aggregate Price across all the docs in the collection. Even otherwise I am not sure how to access the data returned by 
return (id,...data)

the quoteprovider function is defined as follows

```
getQuoteList(status:string): AngularFirestoreCollection<Quotation> {
return this.fireStore.collection<Quotation>(
  '/QuoteList',
  clause => clause.where('qStatus','==',status)
)}
```

Is there an alternative way using a simpler valueChanges() rather than snapshotChanges() to access the data retrieved?
Thanks

Comment: did you console log the object?

Comment: It just shows an observable. I am able to display the collection as a list on the view page though. So nothing wrong with the data or the collection object. Just that I need some of the data values internally for calculation before displaying further. And I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: why do `Array.from(`.. this.qd is an observable on which you call map..

Comment: because reduce requires array is what I understand. Correct me if I am wrong. Yet the issue is how to access the value in the data returned

Comment: I dont understand.. does the data returned _contain_ an array of prices? You are trying to convert an observable into an array.. not even an object

Comment: Frankly I am not too conversant with Observables. What I put out is the last iteration of all the things that I tried so far. The ultimate objective is to get the Price value from each document in the angularfirestorecollection and total it. If you could please guide me on that , I would implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see,

`this.qd` is an Observable which will return an array of `Quotations` after mapping.

You need to use `map` and `reduce` on the array after map on the observable.

So your last return would look like:

```
 return this.qd.map(quotations=>
               quotations.map(res=>res.Price)
               .reduce((tot,price)=>tot+price,0));
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work but with an issue. My Current code based on your suggestion is 
    this.qd.subscription(quotations=>
              this.total= quotations.map(res=>res.Price)
               .reduce((tot,price)=>tot+price,0));  However this throws an error Typescript error: Property 'Price' does not exist on type 'Quotation' This error throws up only when I do complete clean build not otherwise. i.e. it works other times. Not sure what I am missing out on

Comment: are you setting the return type of this function as Observable<Quotation[]> or Observable<any[]> ?

Comment: It works with Observable<any[]> but I thought its always better to avoid 'any'. Will go with <any[]> solution right now unless there is a better way. Thanks

Comment: the thing is you are returning a custom object `return { id, ...data };` which is not of type Quotation

Comment: Got it. Thanks for all the help